# Errors when a design document is edited and an update_notification is set

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I've got a CouchDB 2.0 installation, running on Ubuntu 16.04, single node. One particular aspect of my application has write-heavy load, but I want reads need to be timely, so I'm looking to use `update_notification` to rebuild indexes every `n` writes.

I created a small NodeJS application to handle this, but found that any time a design document was edited, my server would fall over.  This turned out to be because CouchDB was firing up hundreds of copies of the update listener, which in turn seemed to be because of crashes reported in `couch.log`. Each time there was a crash, a new update listener was spawned, but the old script was not terminating.

I have pared this down to a simple case, where the `update_notification` hander actually does nothing but log the updates it receives from `STDIN`:

updates.bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line" >> /home/www/logs/updates.log
done
```

local.ini:

```
[update_notification]
updates=/home/www/updates.bash
```

I would expect to see `updates.log` fill with notifications like...

```
{"type":"updated","db":"transactions"}    
{"type":"ddoc_updated","db":"transactions","id":"_design/temp"}
```

... and this is what is seen on CouchDB 1.6.1.  But on CouchDB 2.0, I see my `couch.log` populated with hundreds of crash reports, and my update script repeatedly re-spawned.

```
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:06.924056Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3061.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3061.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_event_os_listener,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,<0.180.0>], messages: [{'$couch_event',<<"shards/e0000000-ffffffff/transac...">>,...}], links: [<0.184.0>,<0.3062.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 182
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:06.924572Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.184.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "updates" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("/home/www/updates.bash") at <0.3061.0> exit with reason bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context child_terminated
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.007824Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3128.0> -------- gen_server <0.3128.0> terminated with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240)
last msg: {'$couch_event',<<"shards/00000000-1fffffff/transactions.1491989851">>,{index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}}
    state: <0.3129.0>
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.008373Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3128.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3128.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_event_os_listener,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,<0.180.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.184.0>,<0.3129.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 180
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.009436Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.184.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "updates" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("/home/www/updates.bash") at <0.3128.0> exit with reason bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context child_terminated
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.073859Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3131.0> -------- gen_server <0.3131.0> terminated with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240)
last msg: {'$couch_event',<<"shards/a0000000-bfffffff/transactions.1491989851">>,{index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}}
    state: <0.3132.0>
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.074561Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3131.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3131.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_event_os_listener,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,<0.180.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.184.0>,<0.3132.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 180
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.077530Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.184.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "updates" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("/home/www/updates.bash") at <0.3131.0> exit with reason bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context child_terminated
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.188390Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3134.0> -------- gen_server <0.3134.0> terminated with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240)
last msg: {'$couch_event',<<"shards/c0000000-dfffffff/transactions.1491989851">>,{index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}}
    state: <0.3135.0>
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.188829Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3134.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3134.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_event_os_listener,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,<0.180.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.184.0>,<0.3135.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 180
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.189149Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.184.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "updates" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("/home/www/updates.bash") at <0.3134.0> exit with reason bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context child_terminated
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.330580Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3153.0> -------- gen_server <0.3153.0> terminated with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240)
last msg: {'$couch_event',<<"shards/40000000-5fffffff/transactions.1491989851">>,{index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}}
    state: <0.3154.0>
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.330924Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3153.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3153.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_event_os_listener,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,<0.180.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.184.0>,<0.3154.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 180
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.331223Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.184.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "updates" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("/home/www/updates.bash") at <0.3153.0> exit with reason bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context child_terminated
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.331364Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.184.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "updates" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("/home/www/updates.bash") at <0.3153.0> exit with reason reached_max_restart_intensity in context shutdown
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.331476Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.181.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_sup2 had child couch_event_os_sup started with couch_event_os_sup:start_link() at <0.184.0> exit with reason shutdown in context child_terminated
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.356958Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3158.0> -------- gen_server <0.3158.0> terminated with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240)
last msg: {'$couch_event',<<"shards/80000000-9fffffff/transactions.1491989851">>,{index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}}
    state: <0.3159.0>
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.364351Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3158.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3158.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_event_os_listener,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,<0.180.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.3156.0>,<0.3159.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 180
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.369489Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3156.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "updates" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("/home/www/updates.bash") at <0.3158.0> exit with reason bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context child_terminated
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.382849Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3175.0> -------- gen_server <0.3175.0> terminated with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240)
last msg: {'$couch_event',<<"shards/60000000-7fffffff/transactions.1491989851">>,{index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}}
    state: <0.3176.0>
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.384947Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3175.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3175.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_event_os_listener,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,<0.180.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.3156.0>,<0.3176.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 180
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:07.386137Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3156.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "updates" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("/home/www/updates.bash") at <0.3175.0> exit with reason bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context child_terminated
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:11.992126Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3179.0> -------- gen_server <0.3179.0> terminated with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240)
last msg: {'$couch_event',<<"shards/e0000000-ffffffff/transactions.1491989851">>,{index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}}
    state: <0.3180.0>
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:11.992790Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3179.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3179.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_event_os_listener,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,<0.180.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.3156.0>,<0.3180.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 180
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:11.993045Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3156.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "updates" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("/home/www/updates.bash") at <0.3179.0> exit with reason bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context child_terminated
[info] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.264805Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.2873.0> -------- OS Process #Port<0.7740> Log :: function raised exception (new TypeError("doc.meta is undefined", "undefined", 14)) with doc._id 4d1a7b83e5bd85296941dd7ac19e13b6
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.333125Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3257.0> -------- gen_server <0.3257.0> terminated with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240)
last msg: {'$couch_event',<<"shards/00000000-1fffffff/transactions.1491989851">>,{index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}}
    state: <0.3258.0>
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.335469Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3257.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3257.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_event_os_listener,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,<0.180.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.3156.0>,<0.3258.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 180
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.338476Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3156.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "updates" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("/home/www/updates.bash") at <0.3257.0> exit with reason bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context child_terminated
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.588788Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3260.0> -------- gen_server <0.3260.0> terminated with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240)
last msg: {'$couch_event',<<"shards/a0000000-bfffffff/transactions.1491989851">>,{index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}}
    state: <0.3261.0>
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.589696Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3260.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3260.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_event_os_listener,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,<0.180.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.3156.0>,<0.3261.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 180
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.590014Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3156.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "updates" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("/home/www/updates.bash") at <0.3260.0> exit with reason bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context child_terminated
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.607826Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3263.0> -------- gen_server <0.3263.0> terminated with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240)
last msg: {'$couch_event',<<"shards/60000000-7fffffff/transactions.1491989851">>,{index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}}
    state: <0.3264.0>
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.612208Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3263.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3263.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_event_os_listener,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,<0.180.0>], messages: [{'$couch_event',<<"shards/20000000-3fffffff/transac...">>,...}], links: [<0.3156.0>,<0.3264.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 182
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.614816Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3156.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "updates" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("/home/www/updates.bash") at <0.3263.0> exit with reason bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context child_terminated
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.766033Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3266.0> -------- gen_server <0.3266.0> terminated with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240)
last msg: {'$couch_event',<<"shards/c0000000-dfffffff/transactions.1491989851">>,{index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}}
    state: <0.3267.0>
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.766409Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3266.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.3266.0>) with 1 neighbors exited with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_event_os_listener,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,<0.180.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.3156.0>,<0.3267.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 610, stack_size: 27, reductions: 180
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.770029Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3156.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "updates" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("/home/www/updates.bash") at <0.3266.0> exit with reason bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240) in context child_terminated
[error] 2017-06-22T12:40:12.809470Z couchdb@couchdb-01.uk.tote21.net <0.3269.0> -------- gen_server <0.3269.0> terminated with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:atom_to_list({index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}) at couch_event_os_listener:handle_info/2(line:61) <= gen_server:try_dispatch/4(line:615) <= gen_server:handle_msg/5(line:681) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240)
last msg: {'$couch_event',<<"shards/40000000-5fffffff/transactions.1491989851">>,{index_commit,<<"_design/temp">>}}
    state: <0.3270.0>
```

I'm guessing I've made some poor assumptions about how `update_notification` works, but for the life of me I don't know what that could be?  It's also a difficult problem to debug, as the errors are somewhat opaque and even the simplest `update_notification` script I can come up with still exhibits the behaviour.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you found a very old API that was retired around CouchDB 1.0 in favour of:

- _changes: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/changes.html
- _db_updates: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/server/common.html#db-updates